# rest api made in nodejs is not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, rest, http

I have made a restful API in node.js that connects database and return database result as `JSON`.

Here is node.js code:

```
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
        pool.acquire(function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                // handle error - this is generally the err from your
                // factory.create function
            }
            else {
                var query, queryData = req.query;
                query = "call sign_up('" + queryData.userId + "','" + queryData.password + "','" + queryData.email + "')";
                console.log(query);
                client.query(query, function (err, result) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log('Got Error :' + err);
                    else {
                        var queryResult = result[0][0];
                        var dataJson = queryResult;
                        res.end(JSON.stringify(dataJson));
                    }
                    pool.release(client);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

and angular code:

```
var route = URLS.UserUrl + "signup/?userId=" + objUser.userId + "&password=" + objUser.password + "&email=" + objUser.email;
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        deferred.resolve($http.get(route).success(function (data) {

        }).error(function (err,status){
            debugger
        }));
        return deferred.promise;
```

This is not returning anything and get back to error function. But if I hit this from browser it shows:

```
{"status":"User already exist"}
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: What error are you getting? 404? Also, what does URLS.UserUrl equal?

Comment: In network- it is showing 200OK. but response is blank. URLS.UserUrl is constant

Comment: Try calling the API using Postman. What result do you get? Your code looks pretty correct to me. Maybe it's caused by an error in `sign_up` procedure

Comment: procedure is working fine.